# LocationListener with Thread.Sleep

Tags: java, android

My application uses a progress dialog to let my user know that the location listener is currently searching for their current coordinates as shown:

```
ProgressDialog searching;

locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

locationListener = new GPSLocationListener();

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,
            0, locationListener);

searching = ProgressDialog.show(this, null, "Gaining GPS posistion...",  false,true);
```

This is great but I want to set a time limit that this can run for. Can i use a simple Thread.Sleep static instance set at - for example - 20 seconds? This will then check if my location object is still null and will then cancel the search?

Can i run both a Location Listener and a thread.sleep concurrently? I have looked at the Oracle notes for Thread.Sleep but I'm still not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can i use a simple Thread.Sleep static instance set at - for example - 20 seconds?

That would be disastrous. Do not use `sleep()` on the main application thread in Android, as it freezes your UI for however long your `sleep()` call is set for.

There are many better ways to get control in your activity in 20 seconds. The lightest-weight solution is to call `postDelayed()` on one of your widgets, with a `Runnable` that will execute what you want in 20 seconds.

> I have looked at the Oracle notes for Thread.Sleep but I'm still not 100% sure.

Since Oracle has little to do with Android, you are better served reading [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com).